# FInd Java JDK update version and update

Tags: java

how do you determine the update package of your jdk? when i run

> javac -version

I get the following `1.7.0`

does this mean there have been no updates applied?

should running the update from the java icon in the tray or from control panel update the jDK as well as the JRE or just the JRE

Is there a way to update vs re-install java?

Comment: This link can help [Verify Java](https://www.java.com/en/download/installed.jsp)

Comment: Use `java -version` instead of `javac -version`.

Comment: On windows, java has an automatic updater, so why bother?
For other OS, the package manager has the same function, so why bother too?

Comment: @ValentinoDell'Aica Because I would imagine the majority of developers wouldn't want their JDK upgraded mid-project. That would cause no end of trouble. Upgrading core libraries has to be a conscious decision, not something that just happens automatically as and when a new version of the library comes out.

Comment: @JonK you're right. But if you only upgrade the minor version of JDK (no other user libraries) the Api is consistent

Comment: @ValentinoDell'Aica The API may be consistent but the minor version may also introduce new bugs into operations that you previously relied up - it still means you have to expend significant effort regression testing to make sure that everything still works the way it should.

Comment: @JonK By my experience, it's difficult to find the same runtime both in developer machine(s) and customer enviroments, so your code should work without relying on a particular implementation. Btw since they are API we should rely on the fact that with same input we get the same output, just for a matter of consistency, else we would need to work in EXACT copy of customer machine, which he/she never update so we are sure of the application behavior. But in the end this will nullify the benefit of working with a high level, VM based language

Answer (score 2):

You can use the command line option `-fullversion`,

```
java -fullversion
```

or (as other's have noted),

```
java -version
```

or you could use some code

```
String version = System.getProperty("java.version");
System.out.println(version);
```

Comment: thanks for the help. with that i get 1.7.0-b147 .... how do i cross reference that with the update number? i'm trying to get something like Java SE 7 Update 51

Comment: just to flesh out my question more... does this mean 7.0 build 147 .... no update packs?

Comment: It's a build number, and there aren't Java *update packs*. Instead you replace one Java build with another.

Comment: thanks again... if i look here (   http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/jdk7-naming-418744.html   ) I see the following 

"When the version string for the product is reported as "java version 1.7.0_3", the product will be called... JDK 7 update 3"

it looks like there are updates (guess i shouldn't say packs?) since there is no number after the _ i have no updates i am assuming

Comment: You have a number, it's 147. Here is a [list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_7_updates) of all Oracle releases, but b147 seems to be [openjdk](http://grepcode.com/snapshot/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147). There are multiple sources of Java, what platform are you on? And what's the full result of `java -version`?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to update vs re-install java?

If you use Windows java can check for updates. If you use Linux you can get updates automatically in depend from settings of package manager. More detailed answer depends from your OS.